# Fit node sizes of nodes next to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to draw the frame format of a packet with the code below. My problem is that it is really annoying to specify all the sizes `minimum width=xx` of the nodes.
Is there a way to make the boxes as small as possible (fitting the text inside) and relatively place them beside each other? I tried the fit library but that did not really make it easier. When I set `inner sep = 0pt` there is no space around the text anymore. Otherwise the fitted node is too large. I cannot believe that my use case is that strange.
I have to make several of these figures, any improvement to make it easier is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE, binary-units=true, per-mode=symbol-or-fraction, fraction-function=\tfrac}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0cm, auto,
    outer sep = 0pt,
    anchor=north west,
    element/.style={
        draw,
        fill=white,
        rectangle,
        align = center},
    5mm/.style={
        minimum height = 0.6cm},
    10mm/.style={
        minimum height = 1.2cm},
    15mm/.style={
        minimum height = 1.8cm},
    length/.style={
        draw,
        fill=white,
        rectangle,
        align = center,
        minimum height = 0.6cm},
    layer1/.style={
        fill=gray!20},
    layer2/.style={
        fill=gray!10},
    l1e/.style={
        fill=blue!20},
    l2e/.style={
        fill=red!20},
    opte/.style={
        fill=yellow!20},
    phye/.style={
        fill=green!20}]

\node[element,l1e , 15mm, minimum width=1.6cm] at (0,0) (SOF){Start of\\Frame};
\node[length,l1e, below = of SOF, minimum width=1.6cm](SOF-size){\SI{1}{\bit}};

\node[element,l2e , 10mm, minimum width=1.5cm] at ($(SOF.north east)+(0,-0.6)$) (id){ID};
\node[length,l2e , below = of id, minimum width=1.5cm] (Id-size){\SI{11}{\bit}};

\node[element,l2e , 10mm, right = of id, minimum width=1.3cm] (remote){Remote};
\node[length,l2e , below = of remote, minimum width=1.3cm] (remote-size){\SI{1}{\bit}};

\node[element,l2e , 10mm, right = of id, minimum width=1.6cm] (remote){Remote};
\node[length,l2e , below = of remote, minimum width=1.6cm] (remote-size){\SI{1}{\bit}};

\node[element, opte, 10mm, right = of remote, minimum width=1.6cm] (idext){ID Ext.};
\node[length, opte, below = of idext, minimum width=1.6cm] (idext-size){\SI{1}{\bit}};

\node[element, opte, 10mm, right = of idext, minimum width=1.6cm] (idb){ID (B)};
\node[length, opte, below = of idb, minimum width=1.6cm] (idb-size){\SI{18}{\bit}};

\node[element, opte, 10mm, right = of idb, minimum width=1.6cm] (remoteb){Remote};
\node[length, opte, below = of remoteb, minimum width=1.6cm] (remoteb-size){\SI{1}{\bit}};

\node[element,l2e , 10mm, right = of remoteb, minimum width=2cm] (reserved){Reserviert};
\node[length,l2e , below = of reserved, minimum width=2cm] (reserved-size){\SI{1}{\bit}};

\node[element,l2e , 10mm, right = of reserved, minimum width=2cm] (reserved2){Reserviert};
\node[length,l2e , below = of reserved2, minimum width=2cm] (reserved2-size){\SI{1}{\bit}};

\node[element,l2e , 10mm, right = of reserved2, minimum width=1.5cm] (length){Länge};
\node[length,l2e , below = of length, minimum width=1.5cm] (length-size){\SI{4}{\bit}};

\node[element,l2e , 5mm, minimum width=13.4cm] at (SOF.north east) (header){CAN Header: \SI{18}{\bit} bzw. \SI{36}{\bit}};

\node[element,l2e , 15mm, minimum width=3cm] at (header.north east)(payload){Nutzdaten};
\node[length,l2e , below = of payload, minimum width=3cm] (payload-size){\SIrange{0}{8}{\byte}};

\node[element,l2e , 15mm, right = of payload, minimum width=1.5cm] (crc){CRC};
\node[length,l2e , below = of crc, minimum width=1.5cm] (crc-size){\SI{15}{\bit}};

\node[element,l2e , 15mm, right = of crc, minimum width=1.4cm] (crcdelim){CRC\\Delim.};
\node[length,l2e , below = of crcdelim, minimum width=1.4cm] (crcdelim-size){\SI{1}{\bit}};

\node[element,l1e , 15mm, right = of crcdelim, minimum width=1.7cm] (ack){Acknow-\\ledge};
\node[length,l1e , below = of ack, minimum width=1.7cm] (ack-size){\SI{1}{\bit}};

\node[element,l1e , 15mm, right = of ack, minimum width=1.4cm] (ackdelim){ACK\\Delim.};
\node[length,l1e , below = of ackdelim, minimum width=1.4cm] (ackdelim-size){\SI{1}{\bit}};

\node[element,l1e , 15mm, right = of ackdelim, minimum width=1.4cm] (eof){End of\\Frame};
\node[length,l1e , below = of eof, minimum width=1.4cm] (eof-size){\SI{7}{\bit}};

\node[element, phye, 15mm, right = of eof, minimum width=1.4cm] (ifs){Inter\\Frame\\Space};
\node[length, phye, below = of ifs, minimum width=1.4cm] (ifs-size){\SI{3}{\bit}};

\node[element, layer1, 10mm, minimum width=25.4cm] at ($(SOF.north west)+(0,1.2)$) (layer1){};
\node[below right] at (layer1.north west) {Layer 1};
\node[below] at (layer1.north) {CAN Paket: \SI{44}{\bit} bzw. \SI{64}{\bit} bis \SI{108}{\bit} bzw. \SI{128}{\bit} (hinzu kommt bit Stuffing)};

\node[element, layer2, 5mm, minimum width=19.3cm] at ($(header.north west)+(0,0.6)$) (layer2){};
\node[below right] at (layer2.north west) {Layer 2};
\node[below] at (layer2.north) {CAN Frame: \SI{34}{\bit} bzw. \SI{54}{\bit} bis \SI{98}{\bit} bzw. \SI{118}{\bit}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077) Please give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077). It is no fun to read 100 lines of code!

Comment: You can use `inner sep=0pt` for the fitting nodes.

Comment: I think the problem with your approach is not to adjust the size of the boxes automatically to the contents (here `inner sep=...some distance...` without fixing `minimum width` would suffice), but to couple the width of cells. Why don't you use a `tabular` instead of a `tikzpicture`, since your data is presented as a table, not as a graph.

Comment: As I wrote in my initial question I cannot use inner sep=0pt as the nodes have text.
I thought about a table instead, but I think there is no way to merge the cells in a L-shape, right? But if I don't find another solution I will slightly change the layout so that I can use a Table without too many problems.

Comment: I still think the real problem is not shrinking the nodes to fit the text size (just remove `minimum width` and reduce `inner sep` to some small value), but to match cell sizes vertically. This is difficult to achieve when viewing it as a bunch of unrelated nodes, but natural in a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took longer than I initially thought but I've learned a lot.

The first idea for easily positioning all nodes was to use a `matrix`. It automatically positions all nodes but they keep its real size (width and height) and it's difficult later on to draw and fill divisions simulating similar size nodes.

Then I decide to use a `chain` which automatically places nodes following a certain rule, it's not necessary to explicitly write `right = ... of`.

The tricky part has been how to define a double node with both parts with same width but different height. The solution used has been to define a `node` with the field name and a label below with the bit information. With `nodes` having `outer sep=0pt` and `node distance=0pt`, the chain

```
\begin{scope}[%
    start chain = Frame going below right, 
    node distance = 0pt and 0pt]
    \node[F2={1 bit}{blue}, text width=12mm] {Start of frame};
    \node[F1={11 bit}{red}, text width=1cm] {ID};
    \node[F1={1 bit}{red}] {Remote};
    ...
```

produced this:

[image]

It has been necessary to impose some `text width` for nodes like the `ID` or `CRC` fields where the label was wider than the node.

Next step was how to draw layer information. This has been done with `fit` library help and fitting nodes with `inner sep=0pt`. The contents of fitting nodes has been placed with `labels`.

This produced perfectly border adjusted nodes:

[image]

Finally bit information has been finished drawing and filling rectangles on the background layer:

```
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \foreach \i [count=\ni] in {blue, red, red, yellow, yellow, yellow, 
                    red, red, red, red, red, red, blue, blue, blue, green}
            \draw[fill=\i!30] (Frame-\ni.south east) rectangle (Frame-\ni.west|-l\ni.south);
    \end{scope}
```

[image]

That's all!

The final result looks like:

[image]

and the complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, chains, fit, backgrounds}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    Fbase/.style = {on chain, draw, anchor=south west, 
        align=center, outer sep=0pt},
    F1/.style 2 args={Fbase, 
        label={[name=l\tikzchaincount]below:#1},
        fill=#2!30, minimum height=1.2cm},
    F2/.style 2 args={Fbase, 
        label={[name=l\tikzchaincount]below:#1},
        fill=#2!30, minimum height=1.8cm},
    ]

    \begin{scope}[%
        start chain = Frame going below right, 
        node distance = 0pt and 0pt]
        \node[F2={1 bit}{blue}, text width=12mm] {Start of frame};
        \node[F1={11 bit}{red}, text width=1cm] {ID};
        \node[F1={1 bit}{red}] {Remote};
        \node[F1={1 bit}{yellow}] {ID Ext.};
        \node[F1={18 bit}{yellow}] {ID (B)};
        \node[F1={1 bit}{yellow}] {Remote};
        \node[F1={1 bit}{red}] {Reserviert};
        \node[F1={1 bit}{red}] {Reserviert};
        \node[F1={4 bit}{red}] {Lnge};
        \node[F2={0B to 8B}{red}] {Nutzdaten};
        \node[F2={15 bit}{red}, text width=10mm] {CRC};
        \node[F2={1 bit}{red}, text width=12mm] {CRC Delim.};
        \node[F2={1 bit}{blue}, text width=14mm] {Acknow-\\ ledge};
        \node[F2={1 bit}{blue}, text width=14mm] {ACK\\  Delim.};
        \node[F2={7 bit}{blue}, text width=14mm] {End of Frame};
        \node[F2={3 bit}{green}, text width=14mm] {Inter Frame Space};
    \end{scope}

    \node[draw, fit=(Frame-1.north east) (Frame-9.north east), fill=red!40, 
        inner sep=0pt, label=center:{CAN Header: 18 bit bzw. 36 bit}] (C1) {};

    \node[draw, fit={(Frame-1.north west) ([yshift=12mm]Frame-15.north east)}, 
        inner sep=0pt, fill=gray!50, 
        label={[anchor=north]above:{CAN Paket: 44 bit bzw. 64 bit bis 108 bit bzw. 128 bit (hinzu kommt bit Stuffing)}}, 
        label={[anchor=north west, yshift=2mm]178:{Layer 1}}] (C3) {};

    \node[draw, fit={(Frame-1.north east) ([yshift=6mm]Frame-12.north east)}, 
        inner sep=0pt, fill=gray!30, 
        label=center:{CAN Frame: 34 bit bzw. 54 bit bis 98 bit bzw. 118 bit}, 
        label={[anchor=west]left:{Layer 2}}] (C2) {};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \foreach \i [count=\ni] in {blue, red, red, yellow, yellow, yellow, 
                    red, red, red, red, red, red, blue, blue, blue, green}
            \draw[fill=\i!30] (Frame-\ni.south east) rectangle (Frame-\ni.west|-l\ni.south);
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `tabular` instead of `tikzpicture`. It probably is a lie to say that this is the easy way. But at least one does not have to hardcode the width of the columns. The distance of the text to the vertical lines is controlled by `\tabcolsep`.

> [image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE, binary-units=true,
  per-mode=symbol-or-fraction, fraction-function=\tfrac}
\usepackage{multirow,bigstrut}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcommand{\minitab}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\colorlet{lgray}{gray!20}
\colorlet{llgray}{gray!10}
\colorlet{lblue}{blue!20}
\colorlet{lred}{red!20}
\colorlet{lyellow}{yellow!20}
\colorlet{lgreen}{green!20}
\newcommand\lgray{\cellcolor{lgray}}
\newcommand\llgray{\cellcolor{llgray}}
\newcommand\lblue{\cellcolor{lblue}}
\newcommand\lred{\cellcolor{lred}}
\newcommand\lyellow{\cellcolor{lyellow}}
\newcommand\lgreen{\cellcolor{lgreen}}
\begin{document}
{\tabcolsep=1pt
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hhline{*{15}-}%\cline{1-15}
  \multicolumn{1}{|l}{\lgray Layer 1}
  & \multicolumn{14}{c|}{\lgray CAN Paket: \SI{44}{\bit} bzw. \SI{64}{\bit} bis
    \SI{108}{\bit} bzw. \SI{128}{\bit} (hinzu kommt bit Stuffing)\bigstrut}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
\\\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{lgray}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|*{11}-|%
           >{\arrayrulecolor{lgray}}*{3}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}%\cline{2-12}
  \lgray
  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\llgray Layer 2}
    & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{\llgray CAN Frame: \SI{34}{\bit} bzw. \SI{54}{\bit} bis
      \SI{98}{\bit} bzw. \SI{118}{\bit}\bigstrut}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\lgray}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
\\\hline
  \lblue
  & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\lred CAN Header: \SI{18}{\bit} bzw. \SI{36}{\bit}\bigstrut}
    & \lred
      & \lred
        & \lred
          & \lblue
            & \lblue
              & \lblue
                & \lgreen
\\\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{lblue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|*8-|%
           *3{>{\arrayrulecolor{lred}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}%
           *3{>{\arrayrulecolor{lblue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}%
           >{\arrayrulecolor{lgreen}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}%\cline{2-9}
  \lblue
  & \lred
    & \lred
     & \lyellow
       & \lyellow
         & \lyellow
           & \lred
             & \lred
               & \lred
                 & \lred
                   & \lred
                     & \lred
                       & \lblue
                         & \lblue
                           & \lblue
                             & \lgreen
\\
  \lblue\multirow{-3}[2]*{\minitab{Start of\\Frame}}
  & \lred\multirow{-2}*{ID}
    & \lred\multirow{-2}*{Remote}
      & \lyellow\multirow{-2}*{ID Ext.}
        & \lyellow\multirow{-2}*{ID (B)}
          & \lyellow\multirow{-2}*{Remote}
            & \lred\multirow{-2}*{Reserviert}
              & \lred\multirow{-2}*{Reserviert}
                & \lred\multirow{-2}*{Länge}
                  & \lred\multirow{-3}[4]*{Nutzdaten}
                    & \lred\multirow{-3}[4]*{CRC}
                      & \lred\multirow{-3}[4]*{\minitab{CRC\\Delim.}}
                        & \lblue\multirow{-3}[4]*{\minitab{Acknow-\\ledge}}
                          & \lblue\multirow{-3}[4]*{\minitab{ACK\\Delim.}}
                            & \lblue\multirow{-3}[4]*{\minitab{End of\\Frame}}
                              & \lgreen\multirow{-3}[4]*{\minitab{Inter\\Frame\\Space}}
\\\hline
  \lblue\SI{1}{\bit}\bigstrut
  & \lred\SI{11}{\bit}
    & \lred\SI{1}{\bit}
      & \lyellow\SI{1}{\bit}
        & \lyellow\SI{18}{\bit}
          & \lyellow\SI{1}{\bit}
            & \lred\SI{1}{\bit}
              & \lred\SI{1}{\bit}
                & \lred\SI{4}{\bit}
                  & \lred\SIrange{0}{8}{\byte}
                    & \lred\SI{15}{\bit}
                      & \lred\SI{1}{\bit}
                        & \lblue\SI{1}{\bit}
                          & \lblue\SI{1}{\bit}
                            & \lblue\SI{7}{\bit}
                              & \lgreen\SI{3}{\bit}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks amazing, I guess I will write a script to generate that code from a specification. That might save me some trouble.

Comment: I selected the tikzpicture version as the tabular version has these thin lighter horizontal lines in the merged cells.

Comment: @Till It's fine. I wanted to see anyway how far `tabular`s can go, and at which price. Now we can compare these two approaches with your benchmark. And regarding the code, Ignasi's `tikz` solution is the nicer one.